# Pywinauto: click() method not found

Tags: python, pycharm, automated-tests, pywinauto

I'm beginning a project using Pywinauto on PyCharm. Here is my project structure:

```
mybeautifulproject
    utils
        Utils
    pages
        LoginPage
    tests
        MyTest
```

Here is my `Utils` file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
from pywinauto import actionlogger
from pywinauto import Application

import argparse

class Test:
    app = Application(backend='uia')

    def __init__(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("--log", help="enable logging", type=str, required=False)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        actionlogger.enable()
        logger = logging.getLogger('pywinauto')
        if args.log:
            logger.handlers[0] = logging.FileHandler(args.log)

        self.app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'mybeautifulapp.EXE')
```

So basically this file will be always used (`self.app` with be the tested app during the test).

My `MyTest` file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from utils import Utils
from pages import LoginPage

test = Utils.Test()

class MyTest:
    loginPage= LoginPage.LoginPage(test)
    loginPage.connexion("login", "password")
```

And the last one, `LoginPage`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class LoginPage:

    def __init__(self, test):
        self.FENETRE_AUTHENTIFICATION = test.app.window(auto_id='UserAuthentication')
        self.INPUT_NOM = self.FENETRE_AUTHENTIFICATION.child_window(auto_id="tbLogin")
        self.INPUT_MOT_DE_PASSE = self.FENETRE_AUTHENTIFICATION.child_window(auto_id="tbPassword")
        self.BTN_VALIDER = self.FENETRE_AUTHENTIFICATION.child_window(title="Mot de Passe", found_index=0)

    def connexion(self, login, password):
        self.INPUT_NOM.set_text(login)
        self.INPUT_MOT_DE_PASSE.set_text(password)
        self.BTN_VALIDER.click()
```

When I launch `MyTest`, the app opens, fields are correctly filled, but then I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'click' were found (typo?)
```

I don't know why the button can't be clicked. I know it's found, because, when I put a wrong identifier there's an error that explicitly says that the object cannot be found.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried adding an import but the method is not found. `from pywinauto.controls.common_controls import click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the button is not recognized as `ButtonWrapper`, the correct method is `.invoke()` or `.select()` or `.toggle()` depending on button type.

To check how it was recognized use `self.BTN_VALIDER.wrapper_object()` for debug purpose. Also built-in Python function `dir()` may help you to list all available attributes for the returned wrapper object. Example:

```
print(dir(self.BTN_VALIDER.wrapper_object()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did `print(self.BTN_VALIDER.wrapper_object())` and got this output: `uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Mot de Passe', Static`. I guess it's not really recognized as a button... So as a workaround I performed `SendKeys('{ENTER}', with_spaces=True)`.

Comment: Maybe self.dump_tree() will help to find proper control. You can use self.child_window(...) copied from dump_tree output and then .draw_outline() to check it’s correctly found.